# Can I spawn ghast fireballs in vanilla minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was watching side quest on Youtube, and they summoned a Ghast fireball. I noticed that they then punched it and went back in the opposite direction. Is this possible in Vanilla Minecraft?

Answer (score 1):

You'd put the following command into a command block:

```
/summon Fireball ~ ~ ~ {direction:[0.0,0.0,0.0]}
```

The command is explained [here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/recent-updates-and-snapshots/381386-summon-command-in-version-1-7-2). While [this](http://www.minecraftupdates.com/summon-command) tool will help you be able to create whatever commands you're looking for. It's important to note that these are done with command blocks.

Comment: Please don't post link only answers. Bring the relevant info here to avoid link rot.

Comment: There, I corrected it, happy?